# How to return value from json in javascript for Alexa through promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, async-await, alexa-skills-kit

I am new to javascript so i am not 100% sure about the execution of my code
Used the promise method to get the info from the json output from the api for it.

To access the name of a car from json I did the following:

```
  let a, carName;
  await https_post(option,body)
    .then((json) => {
          a = JSON.parse(json); 
          carName = a.Car[0].Model; 
          return carName; })
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

I expect it to return the name of the car and I want alexa to say the name so where would I put .speak(carName)? . So this should say like CR-V or Accord

Comment: `I expect it to` ... so what happens instead?

Comment: try to console.log(json), see whats coming in response

Comment: @NayanPatel where should I add that?

Comment: @MeredithGrey i have added a answer, please try it.

Answer (score 0):

I think in order to read JSON response from API you will need something like this.

```
let a, carName;
await https_post(option,body)
.then((json) => {
      a = JSON.parse(json.data); 
      carName = a.Car[0].Model; 
      return carName; })
.catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
```

Notice that I added `.data` to json when using JSON.parse. If I remember correctly, you will need to refer to `data` when reading the content.

Comment: I want alexa to say the car's name that gets returned so where would I put .speak(carName)?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd to mix async with promises like this.

If you want to use Promises directly, then drop the async.

If you want to use async syntax, then write it like:

```
try {
  const cars = JSON.parse(await https_post(option, body));
  const carName = cars.Car[0].Model; 
  return carName;
} catch(err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: I want alexa to say the car's name that gets returned so where would I put .speak(carName)?

Answer (score 0):

```
const getCarModel = async ()=> {
 try {
   const cars = JSON.parse(await https_post(option, body));
   console.log(cars);
   return cars.Car[0].Model; 
 } catch(error) {
  console.log(error);
 }
}
```

As this function returns promise, you need to handle it.

If this function does not return the car model, you will get the whole object in the console, find the level where you find object,if you don't get it, try to comment with the cars object.